# Why am I getting ?Getting a" error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation."?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Basically new to FrontEnd frameworks and TypeScript so a bit below water. I have a basic login but I'm not able to sent the input values to the backend.

> error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not
> have a type annotation.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import axios from 'axios';

const emits = defineEmits(["togglereg"]);


function dologin(){
    const name = this.$refs.name.value;
    const pass = this.$refs.password.value;
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:10100/api/login', {
    username: name, 
    password: pass
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

</script>

<template>
  <div class="carorbitalhead">CARORBITAL</div>
    <div><input class="inputmain"  ref="name" type="text" placeholder="username" /></div>
    <div><input class="inputmain" ref="password" type="password" placeholder="password" /></div>
    <div><button class="buttonmain" @click.prevent="dologin()">SIGN IN</button></div>
    <div><button @click.prevent="$emit('togglereg','4')" class="buttonmain">REGISTER</button></div>
    <div>-- OR --</div>
    <div>SOCIAL LOGINS</div>
</template>
```

Comment: There's no "this" in composition api

Comment: You're trying to use refs like in older Vue 2 / Options API way.  Check the [Vue 3 documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs) for how to use template refs with Composition API.

Comment: Cannot post the answer because it's close, but the answer provide in the closed message has nothing to do with the solution for you.

Comment: Yep, this is not a duplicate. Just because two questions have the same error message doesn't mean they have the same cause. People unfamiliar with Vue casting close votes...